# Where is the string-pad function for XRX modules?

Tags: xml, xsd, instance, xforms

http://xrx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r111/trunk/14-xml-schema-to-xforms/schema-to-instance.xqm does not compile:

```
Cannot compile xquery: err:XPST0017 Function string-pad() is not
defined in module namespace: http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions
[at line 23, column 11]
```

Where is it declared or how can be added to the module?

http://xrx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r111/trunk/14-xml-schema-to-xforms/schema-to-xforms.xqm uses the schema-to-instance.xqm module and can't run without it.

I've tried those from eXist-db 2.0 and eXide version 2.0.

Or, does anybody know about a WORKING (and COMPLETE) xml schema to instance/xforms transformators? (The ones above have a lot of issues in the Todo list.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but the "complete" Schema to XForms transform still doesn't exist.

XML Schema has too many features and possibilities to represent content (elements, types, groups, etc) that makes almost impossible to create one.

You can take a look a this one, based on XSLT, with an XForms designer:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/schema2xforms/

See it working at:

http://forms.collinta.com.au/designer.xml